# How would I use a method on a model on the model object for the FE (react)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby

I'm a bit new to RoR, and I'm not sure how to use a method that is defined on the `User` model for example. My FE (react) and API are separate from each other so I'm not using any views (which I assume would be much easier to call a method).

So I have this method on the `User` model.

```
  def verify_password(input)
    self.valid_password?(input)
  end
```

and on my FE I would have access to the `User` as just `user`. I thought I could call the above method like this `user.verify_password` on the front end but it seems like you can't do that.

My goal is to simply pass in the target input into this method and it would return a boolean from the API.

Comment: This is a very broad topic and any solution will be very much down to opinion. I would say that you're approaching the problem wrong - start by creating an endpoint like for example `POST /sessions` where you send a claim (an email) and a password and it returns the user if the password is valid or a 404 otherwise. An API endpoint that just returns a bool is pretty useless. Focus on the design of your API (routes and controller), the model method is just an implementation detail and should be the least important part of the puzzle right now.

Comment: I already have the auth system in place for login/register, etc. I have a settings page on the FE where i want to call this method on a user to verify the password (user input matches up with the DB for the user by using an API call) before they can see the settings page, much like twitter does. @max

Comment: Ok then just create a `POST /user/:id/verify` route or something like that that takes a password and returns 200 OK or a 404 if the password is not valid. You don't actually need to send a boolean in JSON if you just use the HTTP statuses correctly and write decent FE code.